# Lost java binary versions and unable to restore them with jre or jdk

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

After uninstalling oracle java I lost `java` command and `java --version` throws error

> java order not found

I'm supposed to have *openjdk-8-jre* and *openjdk-8-jdk* and same for *openjdk-11-jre* and *openjdk-11-jdk*.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall them in order to restore configuration but after doing:

```
apt install openjdk-8-jre
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
apt install openjdk-11-jre
apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Still `java --version` throws an error and `update-alternatives --config java` throws an error too.

In both, `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/` I can find binaries for javac, jar, javah, etc. but not **java**.

How can I restore java binaries and set them again with `update-alternatives --config java`?

(I need them for *autofirma* software, a software to sign documents with digital certificate).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different jdk packages where broken and I was unable to install them again. So I had to:

```
apt list --installed | grep jdk
apt remove openjdk*
dpkg -l | grep -i jdk
dpkg --purge openjdk-*
```

After that, I could

```
apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

And it worked.